# Why are these linq outputs different?

Tags: c#, linq

1st statement:

```
IEnumerable<char> query = "Not what you might expect";

query = query.Where (c => c != 'a');
query = query.Where (c => c != 'e');
query = query.Where (c => c != 'i');
query = query.Where (c => c != 'o');
query = query.Where (c => c != 'u');
```

Output of `String.Join("", query)`: `"Nt wht y mght xpct"`

2nd statement:

```
query = "Not what you might expect";

foreach (char vowel in "aeiou")
    query = query.Where (c => c != vowel);
```

Output of `String.Join("", query)`: `"Not what yo might expect"`

The outputs from these statements are different.
Can any one explain why?

Comment: what is the output you get?

Comment: The results of this will be dependent on which version of .NET you are targeting - which version is this against?

Comment: Is this really how your code is structured?  The value `vowel` needs to be lifted in the second example or else it will just be executed as `!= 'u'` 5 times.

Comment: Good blog post by @EricLippert for this issue.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: Googling the code gives hits related to other SO questions. It's likely you got this code from another question, so you should reference that question here.

Comment: And of course "query.Where (q => !"aeiou".Contains(q))" would give you the correct result

Answer (score 57):

If you're using a C# version lower than 5.0 (where this was fixed), this is the reason:

The lambda in your query captures the loop variable `vowel`.
Because Linq likes to use deferred execution, the value of this reference is not read until the query gets executed (by iterating over it), which is after the `foreach` loop has finished. At that point, the most recent value of `vowel` is `u`, which is why you get the unexpected output.

You can get around this by copying the value to another temporary variable (or by upgrading to C# 5.0).

Try this:

```
query = "Probably what you might expect";

foreach (char vowel in "aeiou") {
    char currentVowel = vowel;
    query = query.Where (c => c != currentVowel );
}
```

Comment: Just curious, when did C# fix this? Where can I read about this fix? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, [I see](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx), in C# 5.

Comment: Wondering why this has been "fixed" in .net 4.5. Since LINQ is deferred-execution by definition, I don't see why modify the old behavior, which is actually more correct.

Comment: @Teejay I think it's because the compiler team has noticed that this behavior is a common source of confusion and in most cases not what the user wants. Also, i think it's more a modification of the foreach loop, not a modification of Linq's execution model.

Comment: @Botz3000 you're right, "most cases"

Comment: @Teejay I have yet to come across a case where the original behavior is wanted. Also, LINQ's execution model was not modified by this change, just the foreach loop.

Comment: @Botz3000 so the foreach variable is now automatically wrapped in a loop-local variable?

Comment: @Teejay Yes, instead of being declared before the actual loop and then reassigned, a new variable is now created on each iteration. And it seems that in fact the C# specification never explicitly stated whether the variable should be declared inside or outside the loop (see the link in Dan Abramov's second comment).

Comment: @Botz3000 Aside from the correctness of this change, I think it is at least a bit misleading since the foreach loop is the only one for which this has been managed. Other flavour of loops still mantain the old behavior.

Comment: Funny part of the article is "*But that said, there are some very good reasons for not making this change.*" with 4 reason explained.

Comment: @Teejay Yes, the compiler team is always considering every aspect of a change before making it. I am confident though that this change will prevent more bugs than it creates.

Comment: Reading this article http://msmvps.com/blogs/kathleen/archive/2012/07/03/lifting-foreach-breaking-change-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx it seems that this change has been made in VS 2012, rather than in .net 4.5. This would explain why *"Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results"* VB-only warnings disappeared from my code when switching to VS 2012 (just noticed that).

Comment: @Teejay Yes, the change indeed has nothing to do with .NET itself. It's just a change to the C# 5.0 compiler (and apparently the VB compiler) that shipped with VS2012. Didn't know VB had a warning for that :)

Comment: @Botz3000 Yes, it had! Now I'm with VS 2012, using VB with framework 3.5, and the warnings disappeared. Just tried Rohit Prakash's code and it gives the new *expected* result. So they modifed the compiler (presumably) for all frameworks.

Answer (score 14):

It's because you create a closure over the `vowel` variable, which changes in time. Store its value in a separate variable and it will work:

```
query = "Not what you might expect";

foreach (char vowel in "aeiou")
{
    var current = vowel;
    query = query.Where (c => c != current);
}
```

Comment: I got through bottleneck by the cornerstone word of _"closure"_. +1 after almost three days , had read the answer

Answer (score 11):

Read about closure. If you use `.NET 4.0` and below you will get different result. In `.NET 4.5` this behavior is changed(fixed). See also how compiler expand `foreach`.

Comment: As for this article http://msmvps.com/blogs/kathleen/archive/2012/07/03/lifting-foreach-breaking-change-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx it seems to be a change in VS 2012 compiler, rather than in C# 5. In fact, I just tried with VB on framework 3.5 and it gives the new *expected* result. Please modify your answer to not confuse future readers.

Comment: @Teejay This behavior is described in C#5.0 specification. Also the compilers is part of .NET framework.

Comment: Probably. But you wrote *"If you use .NET 4.0 and below you will get different result."*. That's not true. Just tried even on 3.5 and it behaves as the new 4.5.